# how to disable video on command line when .testcafec.json has video options

Tags: command-line, configuration, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I enabled video in .testcafec.json file.

But, sometimes I want to disable video on the command line.

For example,

```
testcafe .... --video-options enable=false,...
```

Answer (score 3):

At present, you cannot disable video recording via command line. The TestCafe configuration file supports [JSON5](https://json5.org/) syntax, so you can just comment out options related to video recording when it's necessary.

```js
.testcaferc.json
{
   //"videoPath": "videos"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Old question but maybe someone is still searching for a solution (like me).

As far as I know there is no enable/disable CLI flag yet but you can disable video by adding these two options:

```
testcafe ... --video "" --video-options ""
```

(the `--video-options ""` param is only required if you have declared `videoOptions` in your `.testcaferc.json`)